# finding out which particular tests call some functions?

Tags: python, unit-testing, introspection

I have some pretty fragile code that I want to refactor.  It's not very easy to unit test by itself because it interacts with database queries and Django form data.

That in itself is not a big deal. I already have extensive tests that, among other things, end up calling this function and check that results are as expected.  But my full test suite takes about 5 minutes and I also don't want to have to fix other outstanding issues while working on this.

What I'd like to do is to run `nosetests` or `nose2` on all my tests, track all `test_xxx.py` files that called the function of interest and then limit my testing during the refactoring to only that subset of test files.

I plan to use `inspect.stack()` to do this but was wondering if there is an existing plugin or if someone has done it before.  If not, I intend to post whatever I come up with and maybe that will be of use later.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `raise` some exception in the function and do one run. All tests that fail do call you function.